# Url length, how short it?

Tags: uri

Our website have a large Url when paste as a link, now we want to short it.

for example

http://www.awene.com/article/له%E2%80%8C-ژێرناونیشانی-ئه%E2%80%8Cو-شته%E2%80%8C-چیه%E2%80%8C-كه%E2%80%8C-ره%E2%80%8Cوشته%E2%80%8C؟-كۆرێك-بۆ-ئازاد-حه%E2%80%8Cمه%E2%80%8C-ساز-ده%E2%80%8Cكرێتوك

Comment: Are you looking for something like bit.ly and so forth?  If so, check out http://drupal.org/project/shorten

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're using path auto to create these urls but the problem is that the transliterated version of your title in the url is too long. Couple easy answers are to either use the [shorten](http://drupal.org/project/shorten) module as jimajamma suggests (which is probably the best answer since it helps users with these long, complicated URLs) or you can update your automated alias settings to remove the title and use something else (ex. article/[[nid]]).

However, if you really want to keep the long title, you're going to need to truncate it when used by pathauto. I ran into a similar problem with custom breadcrumbs and long titles so I created a quick token hook to truncate the title. Here's how you could do that:

In your site module (if you don't have one you can create one and name it whatever you like), add the following (this code below was for 6.x) to register a new token to the token list:

```
function MYMODULE_token_list($type = 'all') {
  $tokens = array();

  if ($type == 'node' || $type == 'all') {
        $tokens['node']['MYMODULENAME-truncate-title'] = t("A truncated title token.");
  }

  return $tokens;
}
```

Next, add a processing function to tell token what to do with this new token value:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_token_values().
 */
function MYMODULE_token_values($type, $object = NULL, $options = array()) {
  $values = array();

  switch ($type) {
    case 'node':
      $values['MYMODULE-truncate-title']  = _MYMODULE_truncate_title($object->title);
  }
  return $values;
}
```

Finally, we can add a function to do the operation:

```
function _MYMODULE_truncate_title($title) {

   if (strlen($title) > 30) {
       $title = drupal_substr($title,0,30)."...";
   }

   return $title;
}
```

Now, in your automated alias settings you can use this new token instead of the default title token, ex:

```
article/[[MYMODULE-truncate-title]]
```

A little more involved than the other options (again, checkout shorten) but thought this code might be of use to others with similar issues.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I installed shorten ur module but it's can't fix it.

Comment: for istance after installed module  http://www.awene.com/article/12000-%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%87%E2%80%8C%D8%A8%DB%8C-%D8%A6%D9%87%E2%80%8C%D9%87%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B1-%D9%84%D9%87%E2%80%8C-%D8%A8%D9%88%D8%AF%D8%AC%D9%87%E2%80%8C%DB%8C%E2%80%8C-%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%87%E2%80%8C%DB%8C%E2%80%8C-140-%D9%82%D9%87%E2%80%8C%D8%B1%D9%87%E2%80%8C%D8%A8%D9%88-%D8%AF%D9%87%E2%80%8C%D9%83%D8%B1%DB%8E%D9%86%D9%87%E2%80%8C%D9%88%D9%87

Comment: ok - i see the long url at the the link above but what would you prefer it to be? do you want just a shortened, readable version of the same or are you looking for a really condensed version using bit.ly like processor?

Comment: I want when we use a url in story (copy to word or other place)or send to facebook, etc.. it's short not like now

Comment: Understood. Which link do you want users to be copying: a:) a truncated version of the plain language version of your existing url, ex: http://www.awene.com/article/12000-عاره%E2%80%8Cبی-ئه%E2%80%8Cهوار-له%E2%80%8C-بودجه%E2%80%8Cی%E2%80%8C-ما (apologies for imprecise truncation) OR b.) a radically shorter but unreadable url like bit.ly, ex. http://www.awene.com/a79ay1

Comment: All websites link, for instance it's short, when copy a link to other place like(ms.word, facebook)

Comment: ok - any of the three methods above (shorten, modify path alias, or truncate the alias) will give you a short url but the methods of how they do it differ. please either try these methods or clarify what isn't working.

Comment: I installed shorten and I active all check box, but maybe nedd more setting, can you tell me it's have any setting or just installed?